# Blocking/traffic-shaping of an Elastic-IP URL

Tags: macos, firewall, traffic-shaping

I'm interested in block or traffic-shaping connections made from my system to a host given by a URL.

The problem is that the URL is re-mapped to a different IP address every several minutes (I believe it's called an Amazon Elastic-IP instance?). I also don't think it's practical to map all those IPs - the Amazon cloud is big.

`/etc/hosts` can be used to completely block the host-name, but I'm mostly interested in shaping the traffic (drop frames, throttle, etc.)

It appears that `ipfw` resolves a host-name during rule setting, so it's impractical to just use the URL.

Is there a way to force `ipfw` intercept traffic to a host-name, instead of an IP address?